# Глубокое копирование массива объектов java

Tags: java, массивы

Как можно используя масссив объектов (собственных, не `String`, `Integer` и т.п.) скопировать его в другой массив вместе с копиями его полей? Я использую `System.arraycopy` у меня без проблем копируется второй массив, но проблема в том, что 2 разных массива ссылаются на одни и те же данные (одну и ту же область памяти), и ⇒ при изменении переменной в одном массиве - она изменяется и во втором. Как этого избежать? Пример:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Mas mas1 = new Mas();
        mas1.num = 1;
        Mas mas2 = new Mas();
        mas2.num = 2;
        Mas mas3 = new Mas();
        mas3.num = 3;
        Mas[] massiv = new Mas[3];
        massiv[0] = mas1;
        massiv[1] = mas2;
        massiv[2] = mas3;
        System.out.println(massiv[0].num + " " + massiv[1].num + " " + massiv[2].num);

        Mas[] massiv2 = new Mas[3];

        System.arraycopy(massiv, 0, massiv2, 0, 3);

        System.out.println(massiv2[0].num + " " + massiv2[1].num + " " + massiv2[2].num);
        massiv2[0].num = 4;

        System.out.println(massiv[0].num + " " + massiv[1].num + " " + massiv[2].num);
        System.out.println(massiv2[0].num + " " + massiv2[1].num + " " + massiv2[2].num);
    }
}

class Mas {
    int num;
}
```

Вывод:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
4 2 3
4 2 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны скопировать каждый элемент массива. Вы не можете скопировать массив в целом. Возможно вы слышали термин ["Deep Copy"](https://www.baeldung.com/java-deep-copy).

Вам понадобится цикл for, как бы это не было некрасиво. И уже в цикле скопировать каждый объект отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Нативный метод [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) не выполняет *«Глубокого копирования»* массива, также как и метод [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(U%5B%5D,%20int,%20java.lang.Class)). В новый массив копируются элементы из старого, т. е. ссылки на объекты. Глубокое копирование вложенных объектов, в т. ч. массивов, нужно реализовывать самостоятельно с учетом необходимой *глубины* копирования, также можно использовать сериализацию.

---

Пример алгоритма *«Глубокого копирования»* массива. В новый массив копируются не ссылки на элементы из исходного массива, а создаются новые объекты:

```java
static class Element {
    int num;

    public Element(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(num);
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Element[] arr = new Element[3];
    arr[0] = new Element(1);
    arr[1] = new Element(2);
    arr[2] = new Element(3);

    Element[] arr2 = new Element[3];

    IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(i -> arr2[i] = new Element(arr[i].num));

    arr2[0].num = 4;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));  // [1, 2, 3]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [4, 2, 3]
}
```